Water supply lines are further apart than tub spout valve connections

Hello all. Sorry the picture isn't great, but hopefully you can see my issue.
My supply line for my bathtub is about 8" apart (hot and cold). It is copper mostly then a soldered fitting to pex. The new tub spout has offset fittings that are it's widest are about 7" apart. I am having trouble figuring out how to connect the supply to the spout.
One idea I had was to cut copper lower, use more pex so it can bend inward to be closer to 7" needed. I would need to solder for this though which I'd prefer not to. Alternatively, I'm wondering if there is a shark bite copper to pex coupling or copper sharkbite shut off valve that can go to pex.
A few people have mentioned flexible pipe, but I can not find any info online about what kind of pipe I can use in this situation.
Thanks in advance!

the copper pipe is flexible

The pipes can easily be moved to align with the new valve.
A 1 inch difference is very minor. Just push the pipes into alignment.
Hopefully the connection to the valve is mechanical. Sweating will obviously melt the Pex.

Yeah IDK why this is causing so much angst.

Or
Get offsetier offset fittings. (Here shown exaggerated)

Or
Cut off the entire stack of fittings used to install the "whatever was on the truck" crimp valves on a copper to copper run and replace with a SharkBite x SharkBite straight valve , a SharkBite x threaded drop ear and one piece of PEX  bent to suit.


Suggesting SharkBite because you did.  You can use whatever system you want.
Install a strong wood brace to hold the ears so the faucet can withstand rough handling.    To avoid stress on the fittings from  the bent pex install the drop ears rotated to face the valves (one bend instead of ess) and clamp pipes to framing both ends of the bent pipe and both sides of the shutoff.

I don't see why a minor bend here would hurt. You're talking half an inch on either side. I would add a 1x4 or 2x4 behind it and bracket it to that for reinforcement and strain relief on your tub faucet.
If that's too much, and money is no object for peace of mind, cut the copper pipe lower and Sharkbite it to PEX, which will flex even easier than the copper will.

So use the offset connections:

found in many places, but image from https://ch.vicedeal.com/products/verlangern-erweiterung-dusche-wasserhahn-einstellbar-adapter-solide-messing-wand-montiert-breite-einstellbare-winkel-ventil-s-gewerkschaften-bad?variant=UHJvZHVjdFZhcmlhbnQ6NDkyMzA4OTY3&gad_source=1&gbraid=0AAAAAp0j33RHnv3TWYH1lZFAmJ4utnAvq&gclid=Cj0KCQjwsc24BhDPARIsAFXqAB2A_qKluoFgw5GWPpUMX_qLbmA4tup7E3x6JwU8bhCqkWE0ThHviVUaAnz-EALw_wcB
But next time use a template to get the connections correctly spaced.
